# My GTA V disc isn't working?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-online

My daughter knocked the Xbox and now I get to the loading screen and no further. Would it work in another console or do I have to get it skimmed? It was working fine before.

Comment: Did she knock your Xbox while the game was running, or while the console was turned off?

Comment: Does it have laser-burn?

Comment: You should spit on it... the disk, not your daughter

Comment: Do other games work in your console? If yes, it's probably the disk. It may be that another disk would work, or it could be the console was interrupted while writing to the hard drive and so corrupted the save / installation files for the game.

Comment: yes the disc was running when she did it and yes other games are working in it

Comment: i have read on here that it could work on someone elses console but didnt want to bother anyone

Answer (score 1):

Look at the disc in light.

Hold the disc in the air and look at the mirror side from an angle.

If there is a scratch like circle all the way around the disc, it's laser burned.

Your local gaming shop may be able to fix it, for a small fee or

if you have a friend with the same game, if you borrow it and install it to your console, the laser burned disc can then be used as the game them plays from the hard drive, not the disc.

Answer (score 1):

It can be several things (besides laser burn)
1. The knock somewhat bugged the xbox and it can be fixed by reknocking/inspection
2. It could be a coincidence and it's just dirty
3. The disc may have gotten some scratcher or the tray/disc is very dusty
Final. As with all others, this could be laser burn, have it on 3 of my games

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scratch warranty, get it replaced. Try getting another copy and testing it(borrow,rent etc.).
See if it happens while your signed in.
With the borrowed copy, install it to the Xbox or a USB stick(may have to be the Xbox HDD). If the game disk reads that it is GTA, it will play off the HDD.

Comment: So it may be corrupted saves, scratched disk, Xbox data, profile data. Test the disk.